# Megento footer with multiple columns

Tags: html, css, css-float, web-frontend, magento-2.0

I am using magento community edition 2.2.0 on wamp on windows server 2016.

I want to customize the footer with links in 3 columns (desktop 3 columns, when watched in mobile, it should show in single column one below another just like bootstrap divs). Please refer to the image to see what I am looking for:

[Magento Footer with Multiple Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzoSN.png)

In almost all tutorial I referred everybody says to hide the default footer, add a new block (and enter links there), create a widget of type "CMS Static Block", place it in "CMS Footer Links" and choose the block created earlier.

The problem is all the links created (using html ) come one below another. I mean all 9 links in 9 rows under single column. How to bring this to 3 columns as shown in the image.

Please Advice....

Answer (score 0):

You may use different HTML/CSS techniques to achieve that.
Floats or Inline-blocks would be the first choice

**Example for float**

```css
#footer-columns div{
  float:left;
  width: 33%;
}

#footer-columns div a{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer-columns">
 <div>
  <a>Link 1</a>
  <a>Link 2</a>
  <a>Link 3</a>
 </div>
 <div>
  <a>Link 4</a>
  <a>Link 5</a>
  <a>Link 6</a>
 </div>
 <div>
  <a>Link 7</a>
  <a>Link 8</a>
  <a>Link 9</a>
 </div>
 <div style="clear:both">
</div>
```